# Подскажите что можно исправить или улучшить в данном коде?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

**Сразу прошу не писать что этот код плохой.**

Я и сам знаю. Это является лабораторной работой. Поэтому прошу помочь с этим кодом: может Вы исправите или добавите что-то или скажите что добавить.
На всякий случай задание лаблраторной работы:

Создать шаблон класса Время и сделать 2 перегрузки операторов:

1. `>>` (ввод новых значений полей)
2. `+=` (добавить заданное количество секунд)

Обе перегрузки работают, но 2 с костылем немного.

И чтобы бы вы добавили для работы с исключительными ситуациями?

И собственно сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Time {
private:
    T hour;
    T minute;
    T second;
public:
    Time();
    Time(T h, T m, T s);

    T getHour() const;
    void setHour(T h);

    T getMinute() const;
    void setMinute(T m);

    T getSecond() const;
    void setSecond(T s);

    void print() const;

    Time& nextSecond();

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time<T>& T);

    friend const Time<T> operator+(const Time<T>& rv) {
        return Time<T>(second + rv.second);
    }

    Time<T>& operator+=(const Time<T>& rv) {
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
        second += rv.second;
        return *this;
    }
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time<int>& T) {

    try {
        input >> T.hour >> T.minute >> T.second;
        if (T.hour < 0 || T.hour > 23) {
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid hour! 0 <= Hour <= 23");
        }
        if (T.minute < 0 || T.minute > 59) {
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid minute! 0 <= minute <= 59.");
        }
        if (T.second < 0 || T.second > 59) {
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid second! 0 <= second <= 59.");
        }
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& ex) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return input;
}

template <class T>
Time<T>::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}

template <class T>
Time<T>::Time(T h, T m, T s) {
    setHour(h);
    setMinute(m);
    setSecond(s);
}

template <class T>
T Time<T>::getHour() const {
    return hour;
}

template <class T>
void Time<T>::setHour(T h) {
    if (h >= 0 && h <= 23) {
        hour = h;
    }
    else {
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid hour! 0 <= Hour <= 23");
    }
}

template <class T>
T Time<T>::getMinute() const {
    return minute;
}

template <class T>
void Time<T>::setMinute(T m) {
    if (m >= 0 && m <= 59) {
        minute = m;
    }
    else {
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid minute! 0 <= minute <= 59.");
    }
}

template <class T>
T Time<T>::getSecond() const {
    return second;
}

template <class T>
void Time<T>::setSecond(T s) {
    if (s >= 0 && s <= 59) {
        second = s;
    }
    else {
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid second! 0 <= second <= 59.");
    }
}

template <class T>
void Time<T>::print() const {
    cout << setfill('0');
    cout << setw(2) << hour
            << ":" << setw(2) << minute
            << ":" << setw(2) << second << endl;
}

template <class T>
Time<T>& Time<T>::nextSecond() {
    if (++second == 60) {
        second = 0;
        if (++minute == 60) {
            minute = 0;
            if (++hour == 24) {
                hour = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

int main() {
    try {
        Time<int> t1(19, 0, 0);

        int i = 0;

        cout << "Before adding second !" << endl;
        t1.print();

        cout << "Enter your second: ";
        cin >> i;

        Time<int> summator(0, 0, i);

        t1 += summator;
        t1.nextSecond();

        cout << "After adding " << i << " seconds !"<< endl;
        t1.print();
    }
    catch( invalid_argument& ex ) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    try {
        Time<int> t2;
        cout << "Enter full time please !" << endl;
        cin >> t2;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& ex) {
        cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Могу сказать, что во-первых для новичка очень неплохо, каких-то значительных замечаний в стиле кода сделать не могу. А во вторых - здесь не место для подобных вопросов, в том числе и потому что некоторые советы по этому поводу могут быть основаны лишь на субъективном мнении. Здесь следует задавать вопрос если вы можете четко сформулировать 3 вещи - что вы хотели получить? что вы пытались сделать? какие возникли ошибки?

Comment: @YuriyOrlov, +20, что таким вопросам здесь место: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1762/178988

Comment: @Egor Voziyanov попробуйте конкретизировать вопрос. что именно вам кажется костылем в `+=`? почему вам кажется, что в работе с исключениями чего-то не хватает?

Comment: Хорошо. По поводу костыля в том что если добавлю 59 секунд там будет 60 секунд а должно перевестись в 1 минуту, то есть там 19 00 01 и добавить 59 секунд должно быть  19 01 00 а получается 19 00 60 поэтому использую метод nextsecond для сброса в минуту.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using namespace std;
```

`using namespace std;` считается плохой практикой и рекомендуется использовать только в примерах кода чтобы было меньше букв.

```
template <class T>
class Time {
private:
    T hour;
    T minute;
    T second;
```

`private` блок традиционно уносят в конец, потому что для читающего публичные функции обычно более интересны. Но это не очень-то важно т.к. в большинстве IDE эти блоки можно сворачивать.

```
public:
    Time();
```

Вынос тела функций из класса - это имеет смысл для раздельной компиляции, но довольно бессмысленно для шаблонов. Аргумент "так лучше видно API" довольно сомнителен, т.к. тела функций можно свернуть в IDE.

```
    void print() const;
```

Очень странная функция. Куда print? Дайте ей лучше аргумент `(std::ostream& out=std::cout)`

```
    Time& nextSecond();
```

Почему только секунды? И зачем оно что-то возвращает (нарушение [CQSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation))?

```
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time<T>& T);
```

Ок, но так ли ей нужно быть другом?

```
    friend const Time<T> operator+(const Time<T>& rv) {
        return Time<T>(second + rv.second);
    }
```

Это унарный плюс чтоли? А что за конструктор? И зачем у возвращаемого типа const?

```
    Time<T>& operator+=(const Time<T>& rv) {
```

А что если мы хотим к `Time<int>` добавить `Time<long>` ?

```
        cout << "operator+=" << endl;
```

Для этого есть отладчик.

```
        second += rv.second;
```

Это правильно что время надо хранить в наименьшей единице измерения, но тогда не надо членов minute, hour - их надо вычислять.

```
        if (T.hour < 0 || T.hour > 23) {
            throw invalid_argument("Invalid hour! 0 <= Hour <= 23");
        }
```

должна быть отдельная функция `bool Time::isValid() const`

```
    catch (invalid_argument& ex) {
```

Исключения не для того чтобы их тут же ловить и игнорировать

```
template <class T>
Time<T>::Time() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;
}
```

Для инициализации есть список инициализации. Либо сразу можно писать `T second = 0;`

```
template <class T>
Time<T>::Time(T h, T m, T s) {
    setHour(h);
    setMinute(m);
    setSecond(s);
}
```

Еще раз, в С++ для инициализации полей есть список инициализации.

```
template <class T>
void Time<T>::setHour(T h) {
    if (h >= 0 && h <= 23) {
        hour = h;
    }
    else {
        throw invalid_argument("Invalid hour! 0 <= Hour <= 23");
    }
}
```

std::invalid_argument обычно используют как `std::invalid_argument("hour")`. Контекст виден из стектрейса, условия на аргументы описаны в документации или в коде класса, нет смысла их дублировать.

```
    system("pause");
```

Зачем это? IDE сама делает паузу, если руками запускать из консоли, пауза тоже не нужна.

```
    return 0;
```

`return 0;` в main() не нужен

Comment: Про `return 0` принципиально не согласен.

Comment: Потому что его отсутствие нелогично, хотя и разрешено стандартом.

Comment: По поводу `using namespace std;` совет весьма странный, как и его обоснование некоторыми пуристами(?). Во всех языках используется «втаскивание» имен без проблем, и только некоторые C++ программисты откуда-то взяли, что это плохо...

Comment: @ixSci в больших проектах это плохо, т.к. нивелирует сам смысл существования пространства имен. Вдвойне плохо, когда `using-директива` присутствует в заголовочном файле. При необходимости уменьшить длину идентификаторов можно разумно использовать `using-декларацию` для отдельных членов пространства имен.

Comment: @Abyx, не согласен я с этим аргументом. В C# System никто к типам не дописывает, а пишут `using System` и ничего, все живы и здоровы. Я уже не говорю о других namespace. Полагаю, что в Java тоже самое, чем C++ хуже? Никаких специфичных C++ проблем в `using namespace` нет

Comment: @alexolut, про заголовки речи не идёт. using в заголовках это вообще нонсенс, ему там делать нечего(за исключением не рядовых случаев, когда без этого никак). А что касается «больших проектов», то их отличие от «маленьких» лишь в количестве cpp файлов, поэтому аргументация касательно using применимо к проектам любых размеров.

Comment: @ixSci помимо кол-ва файлов растет и кол-во имен, чем больше имен, тем больше шанс их пересечения. И когда в одном файле нужно использовать сущности из разных namespace использовать `using-директиву` не лучший выход. Т.к. это смешает все имена в одну кучу, что равносильно вообще отсутствию пространств имен. Спрашивается, зачем тогда было их вообще вводить? В таком случае разумнее или обойтись `using-декларациями`, как я уже говорил, или ввести алиасы для исключения упоминания длинных имен.

Comment: @alexolut, когда нужно использовать одинаковые имена из разных namespace, тогда и не надо использовать. В остальных случаях с этим нет никаких проблем. Мне не нравится этот совет как общий, про частные случаи речи не идёт — безусловно, иногда `using namespace` просто нельзя использовать, но возводить это в ранг абсолюта — «никогда не используй using namespace»,— на мой взгляд, не правильно.

Comment: @ixSci дело в том, что заранее не знаешь, будут ли имена пересекаться или нет. Сегодня не пересекаются, а завтра (проект развивается) вполне могут. Чтобы этого не бояться как раз и нужно разделение на разные пространства. Про "никогда" речи всё же не шло, для небольших (без стимула роста) проектов, примеров кода и локального использования внутри функции вполне имеет право на существование.

Comment: @alexolut, это теоретические рассуждения, которые мало имеют общего с реальностью. Когда будут пересекаться, тогда и убирайте, в чём проблема?

Comment: @alexolut, ещё немного поразмыслив, я пришёл к выводу, что Ваше с Abyx мнению верно, тогда как мои придирки ошибочны и вот почему: C++ никак не регламентирует внутреннюю зависимость между заголовками, поэтому подключая `string` и делая `using namespace std` программист не знает, какие ещё имена, помимо `string`, он «втащил» в файл, там может быть всё, что угодно, начиная с `functional` и заканчивая `vector`. Это принципиально отличает C++ от C#(в худшую сторону), в котором `using Something` означает импортировать лишь те имена, что были запрошены. Спасибо за дискуссию, я был не прав.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> friend const Time<T> operator+(const Time<T>& rv) {
>     return Time<T>(second + rv.second);
> }
> ```

Не вижу такого конструктора. В любом случае, есть подозрение, что тут теряется информация о минутах и часах.

> ```
> Time<T>& operator+=(const Time<T>& rv) {
>     cout << "operator+=" << endl;
>     second += rv.second;
>     return *this;
> }
> ```

Проверка на 60 и перенос где?

> ```
> istream& operator>>(istream& input, Time<int>& T) {
> ```

Кидается исключение и в том же методе ловится. Да ещё и выводится на консоль.

Исключения должны обрабатываться вызывающим кодом, а не самим методом.
Класс вообще не должен ничего знать о том, что можно что-то куда-то выводить.

PS: Временами создаётся ощущение, что это гибрид двух классов - один хранит время в трёх полях, а другой исключительно в секундах и должен делать перевод при необходимости.